# Chrome DevTools is ignoring an image with "facebook" in its file name

Tags: html, facebook, image, google-chrome

I was editing some HTML using Chrome DevTools and noticed some weird behavior. When I'm trying to add an image using :

```
<img class="button" src="images/facebook_hover.jpg" alt="" />
```

As soon as I enter this snippet, Chrome deletes it all together, as if there's no `img` element at all. I've tried adding it several times and it I'm getting the same result. However, typing any word instead of `facebook` in the filename makes the `img` visible and fully working.

Further more, when I added that code using an external editor, Chrome didn't show that image, while other browsers did.

Google Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m, Windows XP SP3.
The same issue on another computer with Google Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m on Windows 7

But a newer version of Chrome doesn't have this problem.

Any rational explanation?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging, I realized that the issue is caused by "Adblock Plus", somehow it considered every image that has `facebook` in its filename an advertisement that needs to be blocked. I didn't knew that this extension can interfere with the DevTools too!

The irony is that I'm a contributor to that extension!

Comment: haha, that is irony. This is just one example of why I do not use Adblock on my development browser...

Comment: The way it was making the html snippet disappear from the DevTools is REALLY strange. That was driving me insane.